# Visual Studio Last Build Time built into code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

Many years ago I had VS 2003, I downloaded some plugin that wrote to the compiled backend file the last time compiled and other bits of information about compile time and time taken.

If anyone has information on this plugin name I would really appreciate it

thanks

ps it also gave automatic version numbers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could write pre-build script that modifiers your AssemblyInfo files. The script could execute a simple .NET program to read and update the version numbers and time compiled, or show your command line wizardry and try to do it with batch commands.